# SQL Server Mirroring - Endpoint setup with multiple SQL instances

Tags: sql-server, mirroring

I currently have 2 SQL Servers: SQL01 and SQL02. Each of these servers have two instances:
SQL01\Prod, SQL01\uat, SQL02\prod and SQL02\uat

I currently have mirroring setup between SQL01\uat and SQL02\uat, this is working fine.

Now that we are moving out of testing we want to setup the prod instance. But we are having trouble setting up the mirroring in prod, the error is something akin to cannot find the remote database.

It appears that each server has a single endpoint port.

Is it possible to create a mirroring endpoint per instance. For example so that SQL01\uat has a port of 5022 and SQL01\prod has a port of 5023?

Comment: I am having the same issue >>> did you find a way to solve it ?!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/database-mirroring-always-on-availability-groups-powershell?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can specify the TCP port when creating the endpoint:

```
CREATE ENDPOINT endpoint_mirroring
    STATE = STARTED
    AS TCP ( LISTENER_PORT = 5022)
    FOR DATABASE_MIRRORING (
       AUTHENTICATION = WINDOWS KERBEROS,
       ENCRYPTION = SUPPORTED,
       ROLE=ALL);
GO
```